# Not able to see view within a view on Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to just test things out and have a red view appear inside the blue view however this is not working?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Game extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initialize();
}

protected void initialize() {
    LinearLayout maze = new LinearLayout(this);
    maze.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    maze.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40));

    LinearLayout maze1 = new LinearLayout(this);

    maze1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(20, 20));
    maze1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    maze.addView(maze1);
    setContentView(maze);
    }

}
```

I updated my code to include the entire class.

Answer (score 0):

You should also add dimensions for root layout as well.

```
LinearLayout maze = new LinearLayout(this);
maze.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

LinearLayout maze1 = new LinearLayout();

maze1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(20, 20));
maze1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

maze.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

maze.addView(maze1);
setContentView(maze);
```

Comment: I added the line however I still do not see the red view?

Comment: Post your onCreate() method as well

Comment: My onCreate() just calls my initialize() class. How do I post code in a comment?

Comment: Your code works for me. What do you see in your screen?

Comment: I only see a full-blue-screen and nothing red. Very odd indeed :/